# How to calculate the average value in a Prometheus query from Grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I was trying to create a Prometheus graph on Grafana, but i can't find the function which calculate the average value.

For example , to create a graph for read_latency, the result contain many tags. If there are 3 machine, there will be 3 tag seperately, for machine1, machine2, machine3. Here is a graph(click to show)
[Prometheus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOL9P.png)

I want to combine these three together, so there will be only one tag : machines, and the value is the average of those three.

It seems that Prometheus query function doesn't have something like average(), so I am not sure how to do this.

I used to work on InfluxDB, and the graph can show like (click to show):
[influxDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRxHc.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are searching for the avg() operation. [see documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators)

Answer (score 6):

Use built-in `$__interval` variable, where `node, name` are custom labels (depending on you metrics):

```
sum(avg_over_time(some_metric[$__interval])) by (node, name)
```

or fixed value like `1m`,`1h` etc:

```
sum(avg_over_time(some_metric[1m])) by (node, name)
```

You can filter using Grafana variables:

```
sum(avg_over_time(some_metric{cluster=~"$cluster"}[1m])) by (node, name)
```

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: use [avg()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#avg) function to return the average value across multiple time series. For example,  `avg(metric)` returns the average value for time series with `metric` name.

Long answer: Prometheus provides two functions for calculating the average:

- [avg_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#avg_over_time) calculates the average over raw sample stored in the database on the lookbehind window specified in square brackets. The average is calculated independently per each matching time series. For example, `avg_over_time(metric[1h])` calculates average values for raw samples over the last hour per each time series with `metric` name.
- [avg](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#avg) calculates the average over multiple time series. The average is calculated independently per each point on the graph.

If you need to calculate the average over raw samples across all the time series, which match the given [selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors), per each time bucket, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT
  time_bucket('5 minutes', timestamp) AS t,
  avg(value)
FROM table
GROUP BY t
```

Then the following PromQL query must be used:

```
sum(sum_over_time(metric[$__interval])) / sum(count_over_time(metric[$__interval]))
```

Do not use `avg(avg_over_time(metric[$__interval]))`, since it returns average of averages, which isn't equal to real average. See [this explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95909/why-is-an-average-of-an-average-usually-incorrect) for details.

Comment: What's a raw sample? Is it one datapoint (value) at the timestamp of scraping instead of a line graph across time with that same value?

Comment: Yes. See [what is raw samples](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#raw-samples).